# Unable to set equal row heights in ListView

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I have a problem. I created a ListView with a custom adapter. Therefore I created a new Layout for just 1 row. In that layout I set the main layout to a height of 120dp, but when the list gets created all the rows are not equal and for my opinion not 120dp. Here is the code of the row layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:minWidth="0px"
    android:minHeight="50px"
    android:background="#edf0f4">

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="70"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#edf0f4"
        android:id="@+id/LayoutSettingName">
        <TextView
            android:text="Dark Theme"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtSettingName"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="20dp"
            android:autoSizeMinTextSize="17dp"
            android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Change the theme to something more dark"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/txtSettingDescription"
            android:textColor="#666666"
            android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="18dp"
            android:autoSizeMinTextSize="16dp"
            android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="30"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#edf0f4"
        android:id="@+id/LayoutSettingValue"
        android:gravity="center">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#dddddd"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:id="@+id/SettingEditText" />
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/SettingSpinner" />
        <Switch
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:id="@+id/SettingSwitch" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is a screenshot of the ListView I have right now:
[image]

I want to rows to be double the size of the first row, but it doesn't matter which size I give them, they always look like this.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go back through the source code you can see that `ListView` will call `makeAndAddView(... )` to get the View, and in this method, the `obtainView` method of the parent `AbsListView` is called, which generates an `AbsListView.LayoutParams` of `MATCH_PARENT` width and `WRAP_CONTENT` height,so the height you set in the item XML doesn't take effect because the ListView defaults to LayoutParams for each item

you could change by the following two ways：

1.Nest the layout in the XML one more time:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<LinearLayout
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="120dp"
     android:background="#edf0f4"
    >
  <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="70"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#edf0f4"
    android:id="@+id/LayoutSettingName">
    <TextView
        android:text="Dark Theme"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtSettingName"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="20dp"
        android:autoSizeMinTextSize="17dp"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Change the theme to something more dark"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/txtSettingDescription"
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="18dp"
        android:autoSizeMinTextSize="16dp"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="30"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#edf0f4"
    android:id="@+id/LayoutSettingValue"
    android:gravity="center">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#dddddd"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:id="@+id/SettingEditText" />
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/SettingSpinner" />
    <Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:id="@+id/SettingSwitch" />
   </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

2.Manually set an abslistview.layoutparams for convertView in the getView method in Adapter

```
 public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
     {
       ...   
       convertView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.layout6, null);
       convertView.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
              ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 300));//300 is your custom height
       ...
     }
```